# DockerFile ClassNotFoundException

Tags: docker

I'm trying to create a docker image for my application. I followed a tutorial and created a DockerFile. Then, it's displaying this error below.

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.yuanhe.demo2.Demo2Application
2023-06-10T00:21:50.430778505Z Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.yuanhe.demo2.Demo2Application
```

I wonder what was the correct path. A complete environment setting is shown below.
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N58GB.png)

I tried to replace the last line with

```
CMD java src.main.java.com.yuanhe.demo2.Demo2Application
```

and also replace the dots with slashes "/", but none of them works.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to run spring boot application with docker. in the other side you are Dockerizing your spring boot application.
based on [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/dockerizing-spring-boot-application), the better way is compiling project and packaging with Maven or Gradle (making JAR file), then make docker image with JAR file, then run container from image.

Comment: Thank you. The link you provided is really helpful.